# Send keyboard & mouse events to server application

Tags: c#, c++, input, unreal-engine4

I have two application. One is written in C# and runs on my laptop (the client), and the other is written in c++ (it's an Unreal Engine 4 application) and runs on an Amazon Web Services instance (the server).

**I have written both applications and thus have full control of them.**

I'd like to direct user input on the client device to the application running on the server (UE4 application). I could obviously record user input events on the client, serialize them as JSON, transmit over the network, deserialize and map to what ever function I want within the UE4 application, but that is really cumbersome and in no way ideal, since UE4 already has built-in input event listeners...

Essentially, I want to control the UE4 application (running on the server) as if it were running locally (on my laptop, the client).

Does anyone here know how I can direct keyboard & mouse events from the client to the server application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing an application that runs on the client and listens for the `key down` event. That `key down` event is then sent over the network via UDP to another application which runs on the server (as does my UE4 application). I then used the method described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to pass the incoming message to the target application which in my case, is UE4.